# gulp compile all parent sass files when a dependent/child (@import) is changed

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I have a fairly large code base with multiple projects that share common sass modules.

I also have a pretty intricate setup of gulpfiles for each module that run a number of tasks.

One issue I am running into is the ability to run sass tasks on multiple projects when a single shared sass module is updated.

For example:

```
Project 1 file.scss
   @import "shared-child.scss"

Project 2 file.scss
   @import "shared-child.scss"

Project 3 file.scss
       @import "shared-child.scss"
```

This scenario happens a lot. And when I update *shared-child.scss* I want all project files that include *shared-child.scss* to recompile.

So when I run gulp sass task on *shared-child.scss* it will in turn know where it is included throughout the various projects (ie. Project 1, Project 2, Project 3) and run their appropriate gulp tasks to include the changes made to *shared-child.scss*.

As of right I have the parent file in the project gulp.watching all the included files for changes, but vice-versa is where the problem is. Updating the child and having the parents recompile.

Any information on how this could be accomplished would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly what you want but I'm using this to avoid partials/includes/children from being parsed separately.

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var filter = require('gulp-filter');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('styles', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/css/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(filter(noPartials))//avoid compiling SCSS partials
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

You should watch all the files, including partials, so that the task is triggered when they change too.

```js
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('app/css/**/*.scss', ['styles']); //watch ALL the SCSS files
});
```

Partials are recognized by the `_` at the beginning of the filename or containing folder's name.

```js
var noPartials = function (file) {
    var path         = require('path');
    var dirSeparator = path.sep.replace('\\', '\\\\');
    var relativePath = path.relative(process.cwd(), file.path);
    return !new RegExp('(^|'+dirSeparator+')_').test(relativePath);
};
```

The only downside to this is that *all* the non-partials files will be rendered when *any* SCSS file changes.

---

As a side note: [I made exactly what you asked](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-changed/issues/15#issuecomment-63049804), but for Jade (html templating language), using a plugin that figures out the dependency tree/graph. So *it is* possible, if someone find a way to build that tree for SASS files

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using `gulp-dependents` or `gulp-sass-parent` there days. The first one should be better as of writing this, since it allows configuration and therefore handling of @use or @forward rules in scss.